# How to merge several csv file to a single csv file in R by adding columns?

Tags: r, csv, export

I have a series of `.csv` files that have been created as an output of a `for` loop (based on the changing variable `STOCKNAME`) in R. Each `csv` file is named `XXXX.csv` where `XXXX` is the name used in the for loop. Each `csv` file has three columns but different size for the rows. I want to create a single csv file that will include all the different columns in it.

```
if csv files 1 is like C1 C2 
and 
csv file 2 is C3 C4
```

I want my final output to be a csv file like `C1 C2 C3 C4`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want missing fields to display as NA?

Answer (score 0):

If the files are not too big, i.e. easily fit in memory, you can use a combination of cbind and lapply to create one big data.frame which can be saved using write.csv. In that looks something like:

```
fnames = list.files()
big_list = lapply(fnames, read.csv)
big_data = do.call("cbind", big_list)
write.csv(big_data, file = "big.csv")
```

to solve the problem with the different amount of rows, you append NA's until the row lengths are equal. You have to this before merging the individual files into one big object. Finding the largest object, i.e. most rows, is done using something like:

```
max_nrow = max(sapply(big_list, nrow))
```